# Django doesn't see static css files

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, static

Faced a problem: *django does not see static files*. In particular css.

> Here is the project structure:

[image]

> settings.py (DEBUG = True):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = []

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

> aboutus.html

```
{% extends 'mainapp/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" href="{% static 'mainapp/css/aboutus.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" /> # здесь aboutus.css pycharm подчеркивает, ибо не видит
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block title %}
        О нас
        {% endblock %}
        {% block content %}

        <div id='div1'>
            <span id='span1'>▼</span> Кто мы такие?</div>
        <div id='div2'>
            1 <span class='span2'>2</span>3
            <span  class='span2'>4 </span><br>
            5 <br>
            6 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWycy6WRv7w">7</a>
        </div>

        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

> aboutus.css :

```
#div1 {
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom : 20px
}
#span1 {
    font-size: 9pt
}
#div2 {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 2.5;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom : 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray
}
.span2 {
    color: red
}
```

> urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

'django.contrib.staticfiles' in INSTALLED_APPS is. I use mac m1.

***UPD: I redid the design of the project according to your advice. Now it looks like this***

[image]

> SETTINGS.PY now looks like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mainapp/static'),]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

***Aboutus.html***

```
{% extends 'mainapp/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<html>
    <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/aboutus.css' %} /" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block title %}
        О нас
        {% endblock %}
        {% block content %}

        <div id='div1'>
            <span id='span1'>▼</span> Кто мы такие?</div>
        <div id='div2'>
            1 <span class='span2'>2 </span>3
            <span  class='span2'>bitchdragon </span><br>
            4 <br>
            5 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWycy6WRv7w">6</a>
        </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

***STATICFILES_FINDERS***

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

]
```

***But still nothing helps***

Comment: move css folder to static, mainapp is not necessary, must be `/static/css/startpage.css`

Comment: it didnt help me

Comment: My app has a similar folder structure as yours, but I utilize backslashes `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'mainapp\css\startpage.css' %}"/>`

Comment: It doesnt work too

Comment: STATIC_URL is pointing to the base directory of /static/ but that does not match your directory structure. I actually prefer to build a static folder in the project root directory for a number of reasons, and it works very well in both dev and prod environments. Create a static folder in the project root directory, copy all your css files there (only delete original css location new path is working).

Comment: But can you tell me which path to specify in static_url?

Comment: I copied the static folder to the root of the project (in practice1 ), but that didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: However, I did not change the code. Just moved the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the comments but I can't answer in them, so I decided to help you via writing answer directly.

Basically what you did wrong is pasting `static` folder in wrong root directory - your root directory (`BASE_DIR`) is `djangopractice1`.

But, if you want to have `static` directories in the separate apps, you can always set `STATICFILES_DIRS` to this in settings:

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Comment: I set static to both djangopractice1 and Practice1 but nothing works. Project root directory - practice1

Comment: Try moving `static` dir to any app folder and define `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: It doesnt help too

Comment: Change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/aboutus.css' %} /" type="text/css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/aboutus.css' %}" type="text/css">` - I noticed this in this moment - and it should work.

Comment: But you gave exactly the same link? I checked. still not working(

Comment: Hooray! I recreated a new project and tried it in it. Everything worked out) Apparently I just broke something in the previous django project